# Excel 2007 - Macro for Copying and Saving into CSV files

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, csv

I am using excel 2007. I have batches of data in excel (in columns "A" and "B" as in the following format). The batch of data are separated by an empty row. Each batch of data has unique name, given in column "C".

d1  d2  Name1

45  45
56  65
89  36
35  45

d1  d2  Name2

78  25
45  32

d1  d2  Name3

45  75
45  45
47  44
89  36
35  45

I want a macro that does the following. Copy each batch of data and save it separately with the corresponding unique name in column "C" in a folder called "CSVFILES". For example, the first csv file should be save as Name1.csv and include the following:

d1  d2

45  45
56  65
89  36
35  45

I am newbie and have never worked with VB or macro before. Please help me resolve my problem. Thank you.

Dest

More information: For the example I have given above, I actually want three csv files created with names given in the third row (Name1, Name2 and Name3). And the content of the csv files should be as follows:

Content of "Name1.csv"  !! *This line does not show up in Name1.csv*

d1,d2
45,45
56,65
89,36
35,45

Content of "Name2.csv"  !! *This line does not show up in Name2.csv*

d1,d2
78,25
45,32

Content of "Name3.csv"  !! *This line does not show up in Name3.csv*

d1,d2
45,75
45,45
47,44
89,36
35,45

The code by Adi is not populating the data in this manner. It leaves out the data in the last line in each group and merge them with the data in the preceeding groups (which again all have their last line omitted). I hope I will get some solution for this. I have no basic knowledge to modify the code.

Dest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have extracted your data into an Excel sheet using columns A, B, and C.

Below is a macro that will extract this data into CSV files named accordingly. The only caveat is that this macro works out where a file ends by looking for a blank row that does not have the value "d1" in the row above. To work out where the data finishes it looks for 2 empty rows.

```
        Sub export_CSV()
    'decide on a seperator to use
    delimChar = ","

    'directory to save the exports
    SaveDir = "C:\CSV\"

    'create a counter to track the row being extracted (starting at 1 representing the first row)
    counter = 1

        Do Until Cells(counter, 1) = "" And Cells(counter + 1, 1) = ""
    'create csvData
    'create loop loop until
    On Error Resume Next
    Do Until Cells(counter, 1) = "" And Cells(counter - 1, 1) <> "d1"
    Err.Clear
        If Cells(counter, 1) <> "" Then
        'add text to CSV body
        CSVData = CSVData & Cells(counter, 1) & delimChar & Cells(counter, 2) & vbNewLine

            'extract the save name
            If Cells(counter, 3) <> "" Then
            CSVName = Cells(counter, 3)
            End If

        Else
            If Cells(counter - 1, 1) = "d1" Then
            'add blank line
'commented out to remove the blank line between the first and third row.
            'CSVData = CSVData & vbNewLine
            Else
            'save the file
            GoTo SaveCSV:
            End If

        End If
    'once processed increase the counter
    counter = counter + 1
    Loop



    SaveCSV:

    'confirm a name exists
    If CSVName = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Filename is not valid")
    Exit Sub
    End If


    'save the file
    Savelocation = SaveDir & CSVName & ".CSV"

    Dim FileNum As Integer
    FileNum = FreeFile ' next file number
    Open Savelocation For Output As #FileNum
    Print #FileNum, CSVData ' write data at the end of the text file
    Close #FileNum ' close the file

    'move on to the next line
    counter = counter + 1
    'clear CSV Data
    CSVData = ""
    Loop

    End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Adi, This macro is pretty close to get the job done. The names of the csv files are created as I wanted but the corresponding data are not populated correctly. In every file, it rather seems to populate the data starting from the very first row to the last (but one) line in the group of data where the name of the file is located. For example, for the first file, the copied data range includes rows 1 to 5, leaving out the data in row 6. For the second file, the same but this time it merges the data with those in the first file, in this case, two lines of data are missing, etc.

Comment: Hi Adi, Now, the modified code only creates the csv file "Name1.csv" where it saves the first four rows of data in Group 3, again leaving out the last row.

Comment: Hi, using the code that I have provided the exports that have been created are:

Name1.CSV:
d1,d2
45,45
56,65
89,36
35,45

Name2.CSV:
d1,d2
78,25
45,32

Name3.CSV:
d1,d2
45,75
45,45
47,44
89,36
35,45

I am not sure what you are expecting. please can you let me know what data is being missed?

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. I think the problem was from my side. Now, it works like a charm. 10Q so much.